# Why would an application not find the DLL “boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_46_1.dll”?

Tags: c++-cli, boost-thread, visual-studio-2010

Question: why would an application not find the DLL “boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_46_1.dll” when the DLL is in fact properly installed, and other applications use the DLL successfully?

Problem: when starting an instance of my application, the following error message appears:
“The program can’t start because boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_46_1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.”

Several reasons why this message confuses me:

1. The dll *is* present in C:\Program Files(x86)\boost\boost_1_46_1\lib
2. Another project with similar settings runs properly and does create
   boost::thread objects successfully
3. When I remove the code that creates boost::thread objects from my application, the error
   message does not appear.

Additional details: 
I am developing a C++/CLI application using MS VS 2010 with CLR enabled.

I am using the Boost Thread library (version 1.46.1).

Following the advice on posts about using Boost Thread and C++/CLI, I added the following code to one of my header files:

```
#if defined(_MANAGED)
#define BOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H
#endif

#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL

#include "boost/thread.hpp"
namespace boost {
    struct thread::dummy {};
}

#pragma warning(push) 
#pragma warning(disable:4793) 
#include "boost/thread/mutex.hpp"
#pragma warning(pop)

#include "boost/thread/locks.hpp"
```

I appreciate any advice you may have. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Being in `C:\Program Files(x86)\boost\boost_1_46_1\lib` doesn't help much.

It needs to be in the DLL search path.

Other applications using boost probably have a local copy of the DLL alongside the main executable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the location of the boost libs to the linker search path.

Right click on the C++ project that is showing the linker error, select Properties. Go to Linker -> General then in the right hand panel you see Additional Library Directories. Put in the path to the folder holding `boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_46_1.dll` - typically this folder will hold *all* of your boost libs and will be something like `D:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_49_0\stage\lib`.

Now the linker will search that folder when looking for libs, and everything should work.